# Batch file - Escape number

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to echo url with get-parameters to a text file.

When I am trying:

```
set url=text=2
echo %url% > file.txt
```

the result is almost ok:

```
text=2
```

But there is one space after number 2 which is not needed

If I try to remove that space from code:

```
set url=text=2
echo %url%> file.txt
```

but the result is just empty!

Is it possible to echo "text=2" without space at the end?

PS url in real code is actually like this:

```
set url=%~1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two solutions

```
(echo %url%) >file

>file echo %url%
```

Your problem is the single number before the redirection is treated as stream number.

It's parsed as `echo text=   2> file`, it tries to redirect only the stream2/stderr to the file now